# MongoDB Schema Feedback (Historical Data)

Tags: mongodb, time-series, pymongo

[Nested Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEoJi.png)

[Flat Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pmgx.png)

We have spent a considerable amount of time researching the best direction to go for schema design, and are stuck between the above two designs. Obviously, queries for data will be quite difficult, but the maximum number of steps required to reach an point of data would be 68 (1 yr, 12 months, 31 days, 24 hours).

The second design would allow for much more simple queries to find relevant data, but the maximum steps would be 8,760 depending on where the data is located.

We plan to hand **LARGE** amounts of historical data in the future, but it will take us multiple years to gain enough traction to get to that point.

Questions:

1. Is the number of steps to find the data even important at this point?
2. Would it be difficult to move to a new architecture in the future if speed/steps became an issue?
3. Is there a better approach to historical data that we're missing?

Any other feeback/suggestions/wisdom is definitely appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider MongoDB doc size limitation (16MB) for the first approach and indexes for the second one? What do you mean with maximum steps for the second step? If indexes are used than you calculation won't be correct.

Comment: According to Object.bsonsize, the nested schema is smaller when populated with a year's worth of data. 

Interesting thought on indexes though.